# Plotting a list of complex numbers on an argand diagram

Tags: plotting, complex

I have the following

```
f[z_] = 1/(z + I)

Table[{f[z]}, {z, -10, 10}]
```

This produces a list of complex numbers. Is there a way to plot this as a list plot perhaps. I've tried the following but it plots nothing

```
ListPlot[{Re[data], Im[data]}]
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you want to equate `data` to the table and remove the curly brackets around `f[z]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`ReIm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReIm) is useful for this:

```
f[z_] := 1/(z+I)
data = Table[f[z],{z,-10,10}];

ListPlot[ReIm @ data]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh sweet! thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
f[z_] := 1/(z + I)

tab = Table[f[z], {z, -10, 10}];

ListPlot[{Re @ tab, Im @ tab}, PlotLegends -> {Re, Im}]
```

[image]

Or

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Re @ #, Im @ #}]] &[Table[f[z], {z, -10, 10, 0.1}]]
```

[image]

Comment: The second approach can be simplified to `ListLinePlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ Table[f[z], {z, -10, 10, 0.1}]]` or with v10.1 or later see answer by @CarlWoll